# ActiveReport 14 and issue with SectionDocument serialization

Tags: serialization, activereports, grapecity

I have an issue with SectionDocument on ActiveReports 14.
I need to share documents between applications (the same issue is described in [activereports-14-serializa](https://www.grapecity.com/forums/activereports/activereports-14-serializa)) and I have an issue with serialization.
Can somebody describe how to use the SerializableSectionDocument class?

Answer (score 0):

The SectionDocument document class is an object that represents the generated output of a report.

This document can be used with any of the viewer controls, saved for later retrieval, or even exported using any of the ActiveReports export filters.

In the event you need to have a **serializable section document**, you will then just need to use a derived class.  Please refer to the code snippets below:

**C# example:**

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableSectionDocument : SectionDocument, ISerializable
{
   public SerializableSectionDocument()
   {
   }

   protected SerializableSectionDocument(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base (info, context)
   {
   }
}
```

**Visual Basic example:**

```
<Serializable>
Public Class SerializableSectionDocument
    Inherits SectionDocument
    Implements ISerializable

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext)
        MyBase.New(info, context)
    End Sub
End Class
```

For more information about the class and its members, please refer to the documentation in the links below:

- [SectionDocument Class](https://www.grapecity.com/activereports/docs/v14/online/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document%7EGrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.SectionDocument.html)
- [SectionDocument Class Members](https://www.grapecity.com/activereports/docs/v14/online/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document%7EGrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.SectionDocument_members.html)

Sincerely,

The GrapeCity Support Team

[Contact Support](https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact)

Comment: Thanks, you duplicate answers. but how I can convert it to SerializableSectionDocument